# Error when searching for MySQL FT index with special character and '*'

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am trying to search in MySQL FT index for strings that **start with** 'Ford' to be able to find string like 'Ford', 'Ford1', 'Ford3', 'FordFord' etc... (this is why I am using '*'):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CARS.car
FROM CARS_FT_INDEX CARS_IDX
WHERE ( MATCH ( CAR_NAME ) AGAINST ( "/+FORD*/" IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
```

However, it's possible that the search term will contain '@' or other special character ("/+FORD@*/") which will resolve with the error message:

> SQL Erorr (1064): syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end

I was suggested to surround the term with with `'` ('"/+FORD@*/"').

But the search term :`AGAINST ( '"/+FORD@*/"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` (with '@' and '*') don't act as **"start with"** now (only exact match) and I am unable to search for multiple words ('"/+FORD1* +FIAT*/"').

I tried many variations (including CONCAT) and tried to search in google but couldn't find any solution here.

I will appreciate your advice here.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: `WHERE ( MATCH ( CAR_NAME ) AGAINST ( "+FORD*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) )`   should work

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing a example data and expected results.

Comment: It works but `WHERE ( MATCH ( CAR_NAME ) AGAINST ( "+FORD@*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) )` (with `@`) produce the error that I mentioned.

Comment: User may add special characters and I would like to prevent failures.
User may add string in any language so it will be hard to omit character.

Comment: *"(with @) produce the error that I mentioned."* Why do you want to use `@` ? It has no operator meaning with full text searching you are wrongly adviced to use `@` by somebody.

Comment: *"User may add special characters and I would like to prevent failures. User may add string in any language so it will be hard to omit character."* Well `FÖRD` is indeed not `FORD`

Comment: I can remove `@` from user's search term but I can't be sure that there are other problematic special characters that I missed (like `(`, `~`).

Comment: *"I can remove @ from user's search term but I can't be sure that there are other problematic special characters that I missed (like (, ~)."* Yes you can but i hope the user is so smart to **not** search a car make/model with special characters.. Also you are making a "blacklist" here off special characters which to remove which can be huge considering the utf8 charset

Comment: White list is indeed a problem. I just checked and `@` ca be easily added to FT index so I believe that we should allow him to search for problematic characters.

Comment: *" I just checked and @ ca be easily added to FT index so I believe that we should allow him to search for problematic characters."* Yes because full text search is a **literal** search, when running in boolean mode there is boolean based search engine on top off that.. i wanted to mention that also in mine other comments but i didn't because i assumed you already knew that.

Comment: Thanks you Raymond! I understand that `@` is not allowed (I will omit this character). But, are there any other characters that not allowed? This query also failing when I am using `~` or `(` instead of `@`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible or too complicated.

I decided to omit special characters from the search term as described here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/#in-boolean-mode

Thanks any way!
Mike